# what is the difference between 覆盆子 and 树莓?

Tags: difference, traditional-vs-simplified

As the title says what is the difference between 覆盆子 and 树莓? It feels like 覆盆子 is more formal / "fancier" than 树莓？ Or is it just traditional characters vs simplified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [wiki](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%B9%E8%8E%93), basicly 覆盆子(Rubus idaeus) is one kind of 树莓(Raspberry), 树莓(Raspberry) also include 山莓 （Rubus corchorifolius）, 牛叠肚 (Rubus crataegifolius) etc.

> 树莓英文为“Raspberry”也可以指覆盆子（Rubus idaeus）但是它只是其中一种，广义来讲还可指悬钩子属内的部分物种。